# php mySQL check for unique value needed on Unique col?

Tags: mysql, key

is it necessary to check for Unique Value before insert it in to a database? if the `unique_col` is predefine to be `Unique Keys`.

for example

```
 SELECT unique_col FROM table WHERE unique_col != unique_val 
 INSERT INTO table (unique_col) VALUE(:unique_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to check?  That depends how you are handling the error.

In general, the database is going to do the check *anyway*, so an additional check on your part is redundant.  If you do the check, another thread might insert the same value between your check and the `insert`, so you can still get an error (this is called a race condition).

So, don't do the check, but do check for the error.